# Deploy to Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I was wondering if anybody knows how to fix an issue and what is causing it.  When I deploy to a Azure Website via Visual Studio, I am now running into a problem where the files are being updated (verified by viewing then via FTP) but yet the website displays the old files.  This is happening for DLLs as well as CSHTM files.  I have even stopped and restarted the website via Azure management tools and the old files are still being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not likely but just double check the browser cache and if there's a caching for you website on Azure, also, check your website via different IP address, see if any difference,if All gud, you can talk to the MS Azure Support Team, usually they are quick to response. cheers!